# Which test for difference in frequency of nominal variable

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

Consider a nominal variable A (e.g. smoker/non-smoker) that has been measured in a number of samples. Now i would like to now whether the ratio of A (smokers/non-smokers) differs between samples. Which test would be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *contingency table*, for which one usually uses a $\chi^2$ test:

```
foo <- data.frame(sample.1=c(10,40),sample.2=c(20,20),sample.3=c(30,10))
rownames(foo) <- c("Smokers","Nonsmokers")
chisq.test(foo)
```

which yields

> ```
>     Pearson's Chi-squared test
> ```
>
> data:  foo 
>    X-squared = 27.3929, df = 2, p-value = 1.126e-06